# .NET MVC Authorization Attribute throwing SQL network related exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-authorization

I have defined an authorization attribute like following:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login");
        return;
    }
    var requiredRoles = Roles.Split(Convert.ToChar(",")).ToList();
    var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity).Claims
        .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
        .Select(c => c.Value);

    if (!roles.Any(r => requiredRoles.Contains(r)))
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Subscriptions/Subscribe");
        return;
    }
}
```

For some reason this code is throwing the following exception:

> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have already tested on different controllers like registration whether the web config file is configured properly towards my DB, and it looks fine. I'm not sure what could be the issue here?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Unrelated:  you can replace `Convert.ToChar(",")` with `','`.

Comment: That exception almost always means (roughly in order from most to least probable): 1. Your connection string (whether in your web.config or hardcoded in the app) is pointing to the wrong server or SQL instance, 2. Your SQL Server (or SQL instance) is not running, 3. SQL Server is running but configured to disallow remote connections (and you're trying to connect to it from another machine), or 4. A firewall is in your way.

Comment: If you use a template for creating your service you might forget to change the database context you use. Check you startup/configuration code for different classes involved in authentication.