# Role Authentication Attribute in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to specify Admin Roles access to some actions. So I use custom `AuthorizeAttribute` but I get some errors (below) about connecting to the database which I can't understand because I can get data from SQL and see the results.

The breakpoint error:

> unable connect to SQL Server database

The page error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

As I see the connection to database error I tried to get data from SQL in other actions, and other actions worked correctly without error. I don't know where should I check for this error.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    IsUserAuthorized(filterContext);
}
```

I use SQL V 17.6 and this is my connection string
`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=***;user id=**; password='***' " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
which is working, because actions that need data from SQL and also Logins, are working without any problem.

But I need to restrict some actions for some roles so I use  custom `AuthorizeAttribute` but in just first line `base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)` I hit the error

> unable connection to SQL Server.

Comment: "some error" is not going to help us help you. Please update your question with the exact error, along with the segment of code that's throwing the error.

Comment: its "unable connect to SQL Server database" in breakpoint, and in the page i see "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)" .

Comment: Which line of code throws the error? What does your `IsUserAuthorized()` method do?

Comment: this Line throws the error 'base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)'

Comment: this Line throws the error 'base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)'  /IsUserAuthorized is for checking role ,but as the previous line dosent work this line dosent run.
my problem is in 'base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)' which throws the error "unable connect to SQL Server database"

Comment: A couple of suggestions in the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027078/net-mvc-authorization-attribute-throwing-sql-network-related-exception

Comment: P.S. I assume you are using Forms authentication with user info stored in the database? That would explain why the attribute is trying to connect to the DB in order to check the user data.